# addClass to element inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, addclass

can you help me understand why this is not working?

```
var elementTab1 = $('#tab1 .item-media.modificato');
elementTab1[0].addClass('selezionato');
```

this through this error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'elementTab1[0].addClass('selezionato')')

Thanks

Comment: You probably don't want that `.` before the class name.

Comment: Yes, just a typo error writing the question, edited, thanks:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`elementTab1` is already a jQuery object. It contains an array of matched elements in the DOM. Accessing the first index using `[0]` will return a native element with access to the native JavaScript API (and not jQuery's).

jQuery does provide a nice way to grab items from the array though. It is `.eq()`.

```
elementTab1.eq(0).addClass('selezionato');
```

Answer (score 6):

Accessing an element of a JQuery object (via your elementTab1[0]) call **returns the DOM element, not a JQuery element**.

DOM elements do not have an .addClass method.

The following code should work for you:

```
$(elementTab1[0]).addClass(".selezionato");
```

Alternately, just skip JQuery and use the native DOM APIs:

```
document
   .querySelector("#tab1 .item-media.modificato")
   .classList
   .add(".selezionato");
```

Comment: Is it possible to store inside the array the jquery element?

Comment: No, JQuery stores the DOM elements in the array-like object it returns to you. Truth be told, you don't really need JQuery for any of this. Just use the native HTML DOM APIs: document.querySelector("#tab1 .item-media.modificato").classList.add(".selezionato")